# Linq: forward looking condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list (simplified)

```
[Kind]      [Name]
null        E
null        W
4           T
5           G
6           Q
null        L
null        V
7           K
2           Z
0           F
```

I need {E,L} -> Items where their Kind==null and the next Kind==null too

Assume that there is an ID that is increasing and in order.

Is this forward looking possible in Linq?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this?

```
void Main()
{
    List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>() {
        new SomeClass() { Kind = null, Name = "E" },
        new SomeClass() { Kind = null, Name = "W" },
        new SomeClass() { Kind = 4, Name = "T" },
        new SomeClass() { Kind = 5, Name = "G" },
        ...
    };

    var query = list.Where ((s, i) =>
        !s.Kind.HasValue &&
        list.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1) != null &&
        !list.ElementAt(i + 1).Kind.HasValue);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public int? Kind { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Stealing @Jeff Marcado's solution to implement an extension method similar to the above use but a bit cleaner and not making you deal with the index:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereWithLookahead<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource : class
{
    using(var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            //empty
            yield break;
        }

        var current = enumerator.Current;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var next = enumerator.Current;

            if(predicate(current, next))
            {
                yield return current;
            }

            current = next;
        }

        if (predicate(current, null))
        {
            yield return current;
        }

    }
}

// Use:
var query2 = list.WhereWithLookahead((current, next) =>
    !current.Kind.HasValue &&
    (next != null) &&
    next.Kind.HasValue);
```

Comment: I see an index out of range exception in your solution: if the last item `Kind` is `null` then `list[i + 1]` will overindexing the list.

Comment: Still not perfect: replace `i` with `i+1` in `ElementAtOrDefault` and `ElementAt` to make it right.

Comment: While this solution works, I'm not sure about its efficiency. Both the `ElementAtOrDefault` and `ElementAt` calls will iterate through the list again (`O(n)` each and not `O(1)`), making this take more time than it should. If performance is an issue, I'd avoid using LINQ in this situation and go with a more standard approach.

Comment: @Lester: The `ElementAt` and `ElementAtOrDefault` methods iterate the all the elements only if it does not implement `IList<T>`. If they implement the `IList<T>` interface, then the item will be returned in constant time (`O(1)`).

Comment: @Lester: Any other approach would use the same index made available here, so replace `ElementAtOrDefault` with whatever other method you'd like, and the solution still applies. I do agree that using LINQ here just for the sake of it probably isn't the most flexible/readable, but it can be done.

Answer (score 5):

For a functional approach, you can implement a lookahead enumerator like so:

```
IEnumerable<Item> collection = ...;
var lookahead = collection.Zip(collection.Skip(1), Tuple.Create);
```

The enumerator will iterate through tuples of each item and it's following item.  This excludes the last item in the collection.  Then it's just a matter of performing the query.

```
var query = collection.Zip(collection.Skip(1), Tuple.Create)
    .Where(tuple => tuple.Item1.Kind == null && tuple.Item2.Kind == null)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.Item1);
```

Unfortunately this will be very inefficient. You're enumerating the length of the collection twice and can be very expensive.

It would be better to write your own enumerator for this so you only go through the collection in one pass:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LookAhead<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArugmentNullException("source");
    if (selector == null) throw new ArugmentNullException("selector");

    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            //empty
            yield break;
        }
        var current = enumerator.Current;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var next = enumerator.Current;
            yield return selector(current, next);
            current = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Then the query becomes:

```
var query = collection.LookAhead(Tuple.Create)
    .Where(tuple => tuple.Item1.Kind == null && tuple.Item2.Kind == null)
    .Select(tuple => tuple.Item1);
```

Comment: Cool. Hope you don't mind I stole some of the general idea here to update my answer :)